# gulp loading other patterns in gulp-load-plugins error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, del

I am loading `gulp-load-plugins` and other patterns, but when I use `del` package, it says it is undefined:

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', '@*/gulp{-,.}*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});
```

here is how i use it:

```
gulp.task('clean', function ()
{
    return $.del([...]);
});
```

error i get:

```
 TypeError: $.del is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you haven't installed **del** package as your dependency, please install it using the below command,

```
npm install --save-dev del
```

And also as suggested by **AHC** ensure that you've included as part of your `devDependencies` in your `package.json` which you'll be referring through your `gulp-load-plugins`package.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if it is already installed, then it is because you should include it in the **devdependencies** in the **package.json** file as well, for it to load with `gulp-load-plugins`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.0.2",
     ...
   }
```